# Query entities with count of related attributes in separate field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections. `boxes` and `balls`. A ball can be in a box:

```
boxes:
[{
  "_id": { "$oid": "box-a" },
  "name": "Box A"
},{
  "_id": { "$oid": "box-b" },
  "name": "Box B"
}]
```

```
balls:
[{
  "_id": { "$oid": "ball-a" },
  "color": "red",
  "boxId": { "$oid": "box-a" }
},{
  "_id": { "$oid": "ball-b" },
  "color": "green",
  "boxId": { "$oid": "box-a" }
}]
```

Now I want to query all boxes with an additional field `ballColors` where I get an overview how many balls of what color are in the boxes:

```
[{
  "_id": { "$oid": "box-a" },
  "name": "Box A",
  "ballColors": {
    "red": 1,
    "green": 1,
  }
},{
  "_id": { "$oid": "box-b" },
  "name": "Box B",
  "ballColors": {}
}]
```

I tried to solve it with an aggregation like following:

```
db.boxes.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
    from: "balls",
    localField: "_id",
    foreignField: "boxId",
    as: "ballColors"
  }},
  {$addFields: {
    ballColors: "$ballColors.color"
  }}
])
```

...but this gives me something like that:

```
[{
  "_id": { "$oid": "box-a" },
  "name": "Box A",
  "ballColors": [
    "red",
    "green"
  ]
},{
  "_id": { "$oid": "box-b" },
  "name": "Box B",
  "ballColors": []
}]
```

I also did some experiments with `$unwind` combined with `$group` but I have no clue how to get those information back into the original objects...

Is there a way to count the colors in `ballColors` and put it in an object? Or is there another better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$lookup` with pipeline, pass `_id` as `boxID` in `let`, `$match` `boxId` condition
- `$group` by `color` and get total count
- `$project` to show k as color and v as count
- convert key-values array to object using `$arrayTOobject` in `$addFields`

```
db.boxes.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "balls",
      let: { boxId: "$_id" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$boxId", "$boxId"] } } },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$color",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            k: "$_id",
            v: "$count"
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "ballColors"
    }
  },
  { $addFields: { ballColors: { $arrayToObject: "$ballColors" } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mH5Nm7Rf3nc)